# pyramid beaker + Sessionauthenticationpolicy how they work?

Tags: python, pyramid, beaker

For my webapp I use beaker and sessionauthenticationpolicy. 
When looking at pyramid.security I noticed that the "remember" function of "sessionauthenticationpolicy" return an empty list so I can't set a cookies
on the response returned to the user(in the login view) to track him based on
his "userid" the next time he makes a request.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can read the user id from the session store on the server side. Often applications also expose `request.user` attribute: [https://github.com/websauna/websauna/blob/master/websauna/system/**init**.py#L201](https://github.com/websauna/websauna/blob/master/websauna/system/__init__.py#L201)

Below is an example for `add_request_method` (original source https://github.com/websauna/websauna/blob/master/websauna/system/auth/authentication.py)

```
"""The user authentication helper functions."""
from pyramid.settings import aslist
from pyramid.security import unauthenticated_userid
from websauna.system.http import Request
from websauna.system.user.models import User

from websauna.system.user.utils import get_user_registry


def get_user(session_token: str, request: Request) -> User:
    """Extract the logged in user from the request object using Pyramid's authentication framework."""

    # user_id = unauthenticated_userid(request)

    # TODO: Abstract this to its own service like in Warehouse?
    user_registry = get_user_registry(request)

    if session_token is not None:
        user = user_registry.get_user_by_session_token(session_token)

        # Check through conditions why this user would no longer be valid
        if user:
            if not user.can_login():
               # User account disabled while in mid-session
               return None

        return user

    return None


def get_request_user(request:Request) -> User:
    """Reify method for request.user"""

    user_id = unauthenticated_userid(request)
    return get_user(user_id, request) if user_id else None
```